# UserCentrics SDK fails on SPM

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, frameworks

I am trying to integrate https://bitbucket.org/usercentricscode/usercentrics-ios-sdk to one of my existing iOS Projects over SPM.

SPM could check out the sdk from remote but fails with the following error.
[image]

Funnywise that only happens on my computer, the CI device can compile the project.
Anyone had a similar issue with usercentrics or any other framework on SPM ?

P.S: as 13.07.2023 still no update on this. I had contacted UserCentrics support for this but he didn't find any issues and could not help me.
As walkaround I remove the SPMs for UserCentrics and add them manually as framework.

Comment: Hey, did you manage to solve this issue? I have just added usercentrics on my side and have the exact same situation.

Comment: @Solomiya Unfortunately I couldn't solve the problem.
I removed the packages from SPM and added them manually.

Comment: @Solomiya Any news from your side, I still can't use SPM =)

Comment: Hey @Ilker Baltaci, yes I did! I was finally able to do so only today after updating my Xcode to 15.0.1. I first ran a test project with nothing else but 'Hello world' and UserCentrics framework added via SPM. After it worked, I have added it to my real project and it worked this time too. Let me know if it works for you too :)